# How do I take the users input and have the program loop that many times for a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

How do I take the user's input for how many legs are on the trip and have it loop that amount of times?

```
  int counter = 0;
       int  gas = 0;
       int legs = 1;
       double miles = 0;
       int mph= 0;
       
       System.out.print("How many gallons of gas in you tank(Integer 1-20):");
            gas = input.nextInt();
            gas+=gas;
         System.out.print("How many legs on your trip?: ");
         legs=input.nextInt();
         
         for (int x = 0; x< legs ; legs ++);
         {
             System.out.printf("Enter leg %d distance(Miles): ",counter);
             miles=input.nextDouble();
             
             System.out.printf("Enter leg %d Speed(MPH): ",counter);
             mph=input.nextInt();
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing in this code ?

Comment: It runs but it does not loop.

Comment: extra `;` after your `for...`

Comment: @tgdavies ypu hit it bro :D i remember now it was asked me in an interview this ; just breaks the loop right away there is no { } if it is present

Comment: Okay I got it to loop but it just keeps going

Answer (score 1):

Include `Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);`  in your code to read input from the console. And use `sc.nextInt()` to read inputs.

And remove `;` after `for-loop` which is terminating the loop. And your trying to increment `legs` in `for-loop` instead of `x` change it to `for (int x = 0; x<legs ;  x++)` .

Here is the modified code which worked for me

```
            int counter = 0;
            int  gas = 0;
            int legs = 1;
            double miles = 0;
            int mph= 0;
       Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in); 
       System.out.print("How many gallons of gas in you tank (Integer 1-20):");
            gas = sc.nextInt();
            gas+=gas;
         System.out.print("How many legs on your trip?: ");
         legs=sc.nextInt();
         
         for (int x = 0; x<legs ;  x++)
         {
             System.out.printf("Enter leg %d distance(Miles): ",x);
             miles=sc.nextDouble();
             
             System.out.printf("Enter leg %d Speed(MPH): ",x);
             mph=sc.nextInt();
         }
```

Comment: the continues loop i exactly because of the legs increment

Answer (score 0):

you must write :
for(int x=0; x<legs;x++)
not:
for(int x=0; x<legs;legs++)
this loop will be infinitive unless legs is negative number